# Google App Engine HTTP Error 500 remote API call: I/O error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

Keep getting this error when testing login with the local server. Any idea how to go about this issue.

This is a java project using Spring MVC, google datastore and IntelliJ.

The error info only has files contained in the library.

Really appreciate any input on where to look into.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /home. Reason:

    remote API call: I/O error

Caused by:
com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiException: remote API call: I/O error
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.callImpl(RemoteRpc.java:100)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(RemoteApiDelegate.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate$1.call(RemoteApiDelegate.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate$1.call(RemoteApiDelegate.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.parseTrailerHeaders(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBody(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.callImpl(RemoteRpc.java:93)
    ... 8 more

Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Unable to parse header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.parseHeaders(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more

Caused by:
java.io.IOException: Unable to parse header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.parseTrailerHeaders(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBody(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.callImpl(RemoteRpc.java:93)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(RemoteApiDelegate.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate$1.call(RemoteApiDelegate.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate$1.call(RemoteApiDelegate.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Unable to parse header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.parseHeaders(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more

    Caused by:
com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Unable to parse header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.parseHeaders(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.parseTrailerHeaders(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBody(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.callImpl(RemoteRpc.java:93)
        at 

com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:48)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(RemoteApiDelegate.java:45)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate$1.call(RemoteApiDelegate.java:56)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate$1.call(RemoteApiDelegate.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Powered by Jetty://
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error was because of the Internet bandwidth. When we switched the location where better Internet was provided, the problem was gone.